# How Can I Write a LINQ Query to Get Content Within the Last Seven Days?

Tags: c#, linq

I have this LINQ query:

```
Contents.Where(Content => Content.Categories.Contains("top story") And Content.RunDate.Value <= DateTime.Now)
.Distinct() 
.OrderByDescending(Content => Content.RunDate)
.Take(4)
```

I need to modify it so it only grabs content that's no more than seven days old. Any idea how I could do that?

Comment: So you mean when the content's rundate is bigger than or equal to the current date minus 7 days?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DateTime.Now.AddDays(count)` where `count` can be even negative value

```
Contents.Where(content => content.RunDate.Value >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7) &&  
                          content.RunDate.Value <= DateTime.Now)
```

Comment: That looks great! I'll test it out first thing in the morning. Thank you for the quick answer!

Comment: Unfortunately, the AddDays method isn't supported in my environment. It errors out. Is there another way?

Comment: @eighthnote what's wrong in your environment? what error is raised?

Comment: try the following: `DateTime.Now.Subtract(new TimeSpan(7, 0, 0, 0))`

Comment: I couldn't get these to work in my environment, but I'm willing to bet they would normally work based on other documentation I've read. Thanks!